# Handling columns that need updating after initial creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am looking for a best practice on how to deal with this situation. I have a model called Fixture where I create fixtures for say a football match, after the game has finished I want to be able to edit that fixture and log the result for each team, but I am unsure on how to set my form up.

Ideally I want to be able to create a new fixture without the result parts showing and then when I edit the fixture the form will have those parts, so something like this:

New

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">
    <%= form_for @fixture, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Create New Fixture</legend>
         <div class="form-group">
           <%= f.label :tournament_id  %>
           <%= f.collection_select :tournament_id, Tournament.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Please Select a Tournament" }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
         </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :home_team %>
          <%= f.text_field :home_team, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Home Team' %>
        </div>

       
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :away_team %>
          <%= f.text_field :away_team, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Away Team' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :kickoff_time %>
          <%= f.time_select :kickoff_time, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Edit

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well">
    <%= form_for @fixture, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Edit Fixture</legend>
         <div class="form-group">
           <%= f.label :tournament_id  %>
           <%= f.collection_select :tournament_id, Tournament.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Please Select a Tournament" }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
         </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :home_team %>
          <%= f.text_field :home_team, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Home Team' %>
        </div>

       
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :away_team %>
          <%= f.text_field :away_team, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Away Team' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :kickoff_time %>
          <%= f.time_select :kickoff_time, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :home_team_result %>
          <%= f.text_field :home_team_result, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :away_team_result %>
          <%= f.time_select :away_team_result, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

At the moment when trying to access the edit form I am getting the error:

```
undefined method error :home_team_result
```

I am not sure if this has something to do with the fact that my column is set as :integer for that.

This is my schema:

```
create_table "fixtures", force: true do |t|
t.string   "home_team"
t.string   "away_team"
t.time     "kickoff_time"
t.integer  "tournament_id"
t.integer  "home_score_result"
t.integer  "away_score_result"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

A couple of ideas have crossed my mind:

1. Hide the home_team_result and away_team_result on the new form and assign default values of 0
2. Again hide the columns and have a button 'Add result' to reveal the fields

But I'm not sure that hiding the fields is the answer as that is open to manipulation. Ideally I would like to put some logic in that deals with this in a 'Rails Way', if that makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you have a result that belongs to a fixture?

Comment: I was thinking that but there will only ever be one result to a fixture so is there any point?

Comment: Up to you, there are pros and cons.  For instance you wouldn't need to hide anything, but if you do end up just doing that `unless @fixture.new_record? #put in score fields end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error `undefined method error :home_team_result`, we can say that there is no field named `home_team_result` in `Fixture` model.

`home_team_result` must be an attribute in your `Fixture` model. Make it either a virtual attribute (using `attr_accessor`) or create a column in the `fixtures` table named `home_team_result`.

**UPDATE**

Actual column names in the table `fixtures` are `home_score_result` and `away_score_result` whereas in the view you are accessing `home_team_result` and `away_team_result`. Hence, the error.

Comment: thanks but the fields exist, ive updated my question with my schema, do i need to change the column type?

Comment: Take a look, its wrongly named as `home_score_result` whereas in view you are calling `home_team_result`

Comment: @Richlewis Also, found out that another column is named incorrectly. See `UPDATE` section in the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Have a hot coffee :)